# External guest users locked out of Azure AD; Error Code 530004, "AcceptCompliantDevice setting isn't configured for this organization"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, policy

Without any changes or configuration updates, all external guest users were locked out of our main Azure Active Directory.

The users would receive the following after passing the username/password login prompt:

- Error Code: 530004
- ...
- App name: Azure Portal App
- Device identifier: Not available
- Device platform: macOS
- Device state: Unregistered

After checking the sign-in logs, i would see this error code:

> AcceptCompliantDevice setting isn't configured for this organization. The admin needs to configure this setting to allow external users access to protected resources.

I've tried disabling every single Conditional Access policy we have for our tenant, recreating users, checking every setting up and down. This is only happening to one of our tenants, the others are normal

Has anyone ever come across a similar error code? I've scoured the internet for 'AcceptCompliantDevice' and haven't found anything

Comment: This seemed to be a backend issue on Microsoft's part. Had an answer to this post that was taken down/deleted since that linked to this [forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/712177/looking-for-information-on-sign-in-error-code-5300.html). 
Here it seems there were a lot more people having the same issue starting the week of. They all seemed to have their issue resolve itself without any updates or interference.